# How to use XDocument and Linq to read in a list of parent attribute concatenated with child comment

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm new to Linq and XDocument and I can't find a similar problem with a solution anywhere, so here goes:

Here's the XML I'm trying to parse in:

```
<environment>
 <objectBuilder>
  <service id="1">
   <!--Service:"MagicService">
  </service>
  <service id="2">
   <!--Service:"RubbishService">
  </service>
  <service id="3">
   <!--Service:"MediocreService">
  </service>
 </objectBuilder>
</environment>
```

I want to use end up with a list that looks like:

```
("1 MagicService","2 RubbishService","3 MediocreService")
```

I've already tried reading the comments and ids into two different lists, then combining them, but this is not a good enough solution, as in my real world problem there could be services without the name commented in.

My current solution looks like this:

```
List<string> comments = doc.Elements("Environment")
                        .Elements("objectBuilder")
                        .Elements("service")
                        .Nodes()
                        .OfType<XComment>()
                        .Select(c => c.Value)
                        .Where(c=> c.StartsWith("Service"))
                        .ToList());

List<string> serviceGuides = doc.Elements("Environment")
                        .Elements("objectBuilder")
                        .Elements("service")
                        .Attributes(XName.Get("id"))
                        .Select(c => c.Value)
                        .ToList());
```

then I go through a for-loop and literally concatenate them, if the lists are the same size.  There has got to be a more elegant solution?

Thanks for your help, sorry if it's a repeat/dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is one possible way :**

```
var result = (from service in doc.Elements("environment")
                                 .Elements("objectBuilder")
                                 .Elements("service")
                     //get service id attribute
              select (string)service.Attribute("id")
                      + " " +
                     //get the first comment node which value starts with "Service"
                     //and then extract the value between first quotes pair
                      service.Nodes()
                             .OfType<XComment>()
                             .Select(c => c.Value)
                             .FirstOrDefault(c => c.StartsWith("Service"))
                             .Split('"')[1]
             ).ToList();

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pgv3DO)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
1 MagicService
2 RubbishService
3 MediocreService
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try these out on Monday.  I seriously doubt I would've gotten these without doing a lot of reading around Linq so thanks again.

Comment: These both worked chaps/chapettes and I learned a lot playing around with your answers so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var serviceElements = xDoc.Elements("environment")
    .Elements("objectBuilder")
    .Elements("service")                
    .ToList();

var result = (from element in serviceElements
    let attribute = element.Attribute("id").Value
    let name = element
        .Nodes()
        .OfType<XComment>()
        .Select(c => c.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.StartsWith("Service"))
        .Split('"')[1]
    select string.Format("{0} {1}", attribute, name)).ToList();
```

[Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is perfect for things like this. You can write the loop, and resharper will help you convert it to linq. You could easily combine the two expressions above. You may also want to add null reference checking.